# Continue to next index by NSbutton Swift

Tags: swift

I'm looking to utilize a "next" button for my app that's playing Youtube videos. My hopes are for the button to increase the index by 1 each time it is clicked. But I can only find info on `.startIndex` and I can't figure out how to continue adding one. The code is here:

```
@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
}

@IBOutlet weak var myWebView: WebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let videoCode = ["ufynqs_COF4", "MXqjDRQbibw", "T3JgUT-fa3A"]
    // attempt to add to index
    let i = videoCode.index(videoCode.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
    print(i)

    let url = URL(string: "https://youtube.com/embed/\(videoCode[i])")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.setValue("https://youtube.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Referer")
    self.myWebView.mainFrame.load(request)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the token array to the top level of the class and create a counter

```
let videoCode = ["ufynqs_COF4", "MXqjDRQbibw", "T3JgUT-fa3A"]
var counter = 0
```

As the code to load the next video is used twice create a method. It increments (and wraps around to zero) the counter.

```
func loadNextVideo()
{
    let url = URL(string: "https://youtube.com/embed")!.appendingPathComponent(videoCode[counter])
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("https://youtube.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Referer")
    self.myWebView.mainFrame.load(request)
    counter = (counter + 1) % videoCode.count
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` and in the `IBAction` just call the method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadNextVideo()
}

@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
    loadNextVideo()
}
```